# Connect nested models django rest framework API serializer

Tags: django, rest, api, django-models, django-rest-framework

I want to achieve this: a API to get all products for a category.

#### Models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    main_category = models.CharField(max_length=200, default = '')

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.main_category)

class Subcategory(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sub_category = models.CharField(max_length=200, default = '')

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.sub_category)

class Products(models.Model):
    sub_category = models.ForeignKey(Subcategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default = '')

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.product_name)
```

#### Views.py

```
class ProductCategoryFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    category = django_filters.CharFilter(name="category__main_category")

    class Meta:
        model = Products
        fields = ['category']

class ProductCategoryListAPIView(ListAPIView):

    queryset = Products.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductCategorySerializer
    filter_class = ProductCategoryFilter
```

#### Serializers.py

```
class ProductCategorySerializer(ModelSerializer):

    #category_name = serializers.CharField(source='category.main_category')
    category_name = CategorySerializer(source='category_set')
    class Meta:
        model = Products
        fields = [
        'category_name',
        'product_name',
        ]
```

#### AttributeError at /api/productcategories/

I get `AttributeError` when attempting to get a value for field `category_name` on serializer `ProductCategorySerializer`. The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Products` instance.

Original exception text was: 'Products' object has no attribute 'category'.

And I want the output like this:

```
[
{
    "category_name": "main category 1",
    "product_name": "product 1"
},
{
    "category_name": "main category 1",
    "product_name": "product 2"
},..........
```

OR output like this :

```
[
{
   "main category 1" :{ "product 1", "product 2"...}
```

Comment: When did you get the attribute error? What were you trying to do?

Comment: I was trying to get direct output relation between Category model and product model without showing Subcategory model fields

Comment: One person answered this on a facebook portal
https://hastebin.com/pafugudimi.scala

Comment: and filtering can be done with this: https://hastebin.com/misepeqada.py